# CoreML – How to create a simple MLFeatureProvider class

Tags: swift, macos, coreml, coremltools

I have a `MLModel` that contains one input column called `length` and one output column called `depth`.

You give it a length and it predicts a depth.

I know that there are other ways of doing this but this is for the whole purpose of learning CoreML.

I need to build a `MLFeatureProvider` class to get that length and output a depth.

I am not sure how to create that class because this is the first time I am dealing with CoreML and because, as usual, Apple do not cares to create decent documentation.

So this is what I have

```
class FeatureProviderX: MLFeatureProvider {
  var featureNames: Set<String> {
    get {
      return  ["length", "depth"]
    }
  }

  func featureValue(for featureName: String) -> MLFeatureValue? {
    guard featureName == "length" else {
      return MLFeatureValue(????????????) \\1
    }
  }

}
```

I am not sure if this class is remotely correct.

If this is correct, how should `\\1` be written?

Comment: I would disagree that documentation is not decent (although there _are_ some rare cases that is non-existent altogether) (there is written documentation, example projects & a fair amount of in-depth information about CoreML in the form of  WWDC sessions). Having said that, you could have a look at [`MLDictionaryFeatureProvider`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreml/mldictionaryfeatureprovider) which is a convenience wrapper for a dictionary that maps all its keys to their respective values (as `MLFeatureValue`s).

Comment: Sorry to disagree but every doc apple writes stink infinity squared plus infinity. I have learnt programming on old school manuals and books, written by people who loved writing documentation. On everything Apple writes it is obvious disdain, vagueness, lack of respect for developers. They are a relatively good company for customers but not for developers. There is an old school saying about Apple x Developers that I found to be correct: "Apple is not your friend".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matthijs Hollemans was in the right track and gave me clues on how to solve that but, unfortunately his solution was lacking a lot of stuff.

After a while I have figured out the correct solution...

```
class FeatureProviderX: MLFeatureProvider {

  var featureNames: Set<String> {
    get {
      return  ["length"]
    }
  }

  var sorteio: Double

  init(length: Double) {
    self.length = length
  }

  func featureValue(for featureName: String) -> MLFeatureValue? {
    if featureName == "length" {
      return MLFeatureValue(double: length)
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
class FeatureProviderX: MLFeatureProvider {
  let length: Double

  init(length: Double) {
    self.length = length
  }

  func featureValue(for featureName: String) -> MLFeatureValue? {
    guard featureName == "length" else {
      return MLFeatureValue(double: length)
    }
  }

  ...
```

To use this to make predictions, create a new instance of `FeatureProviderX` and pass it to your `MLModel` class.

Comment: Not working for me. I tells me that the class lacks an initializer. When I ask Xcode to fix it adds a line `var featureNames: Set<String>` at the beginning. Then it fails on the init with the message `return from initializer without initializing all stored properties`. It also fails on `func featureValue`... I guess it needs a return nil after the guard. Anyway, it is not working.

Comment: I had hoped it was obvious that my answer wasn't a complete solution, just a way to point you in the right direction. In any case, I forgot to mention that the easiest solution is to make an `MLDictionaryFeatureProvider` instance: `let provider = MLDictionaryFeatureProvider(dictionary: ["length": 1234])`.